# Update a Variable Dynamically with flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to create a script with flask that increments or decrements a value by ten by clicking a button. I alraeady have a script that does this in the backend, but I am having trouble displaying and dynamically updating this value in the frontend. Basically, I want to change this value in the frontend and backend at the same time without refressing the page.

Here is the Backend Code (shortened to include the page in question):

`app.py` - **The Flask App**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__) 
#motor = Motor(17, 18)

def setBPM(current, change=0):
    return ((current < 200) & (change > 0))*(current+change) + ((current > 30) & (change < 0))*(current+change)


@app.route('/pulse')
def pulse():
    return render_template("pulse.html")

@app.route('/pulseUP', methods=['POST'])
def pulseUp():
    BPM = setBPM(BPM, 10)
    return (render_template('pulse.html', get_BPM_var=BPM))

@app.route('/pulseDOWN', methods=['POST'])
def pulseDwn():
    BPM = setBPM(BPM, -10)
    return (render_template('pulse.html', get_BPM_var=BPM))

@app.context_processor
def get_BPM_var():
    return dict(get_BPM_var=BPM)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**Frontend** - `pulse.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=800px, inital-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
<div id="grid-pulse">
    <div class="cell-pulse">
        <form action="/pulseUP/" method="post"><input type="submit" value="+" /></form>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-pulse"></div>
    <div class="cell-pulse">
        <div class="numbkgnd">
            <h3 id="BPMID">{{ get_BPM_var }}&#13;BPM</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-pulse"></div>
    <div class="cell-pulse">
        <form action="/pulseDOWN/" method="post"><input type="submit" value="-" /></form>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-pulse"></div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
<script>
    $("#BPMID").keyup(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/pulse",
            type: "get",
            data: { jsdata: text },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#BPMID").html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {

            }
        });
    });
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use ajax to update the value, but I am not familair with javascript in the slightest. Any help would be greatly apprieciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example is based on a [range slider](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) whose value corresponds to the speed sent to the server. The value can be increased and decreased in increments of 10.
When a change event is triggered, the browser sends an AJAX POST type request to the server using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The request in JSON format contains the current value of the slider.
The server sets the received value as long as it is within the permitted range and replies in JSON format with the current speed.
After receiving the answer, the output in the browser is now adjusted, i.e. the value is output as text and set as the new value of the slider.
In addition to the slider, two buttons can also be used to set the value. Pressing it sets the slider's value and triggers its change event. After that, the process remains the same.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    jsonify, 
    render_template, 
    request
)

class Motor:
    def __init__(self):
        self._rpm = 30

    @property
    def rpm(self):
        return self._rpm
    
    @rpm.setter
    def rpm(self, value):
        if 30 <= value <= 200:
            self._rpm = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Value range must be between 30 and 200.')

app = Flask(__name__)
motor = Motor()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    v = motor.rpm
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.post('/adjust-speed')
def adjust_speed():
    v = motor.rpm
    try:
        motor.rpm = int(request.get_json(force=True).get('v'))
        v = motor.rpm
    finally:
        return jsonify(**locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Control</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="range" min="30" max="200" value="{{ v }}" step="10" id="speed">
    <p>Velocity: <output id="value">{{ v }}</output></p>
    <button id="btn-dec">-</button>
    <button id="btn-acc">+</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (() => {
            
            /** Send the expected speed to the server. */
            const adjustSpeed = async (value) => {
                const data = await fetch('/adjust-speed', {
                    method: 'post', 
                    body: JSON.stringify({ v: value })
                }).then(resp => resp.ok && resp.json());
                if (!data || !data.v) throw new Error('Error adjusting speed.');
                return data.v;
            };

            const outputValue = document.getElementById('value');
            const speedSlider = document.getElementById('speed');
            speedSlider.addEventListener('change', async function() {
                // Send the slider's value to the server and 
                // output the actual speed obtained.
                try {
                    const v = await adjustSpeed(Number(this.value));
                    this.value = v;
                    outputValue.innerText = v;
                } catch(err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });

            const buttonAcc = document.getElementById('btn-acc');
            buttonAcc.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Set the new value of the slider and trigger the change event. 
                const value = Number(speedSlider.value), step = Number(speedSlider.step);
                speedSlider.value = value + step;
                speedSlider.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            });

            const buttonDec = document.getElementById('btn-dec');
            buttonDec.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Set the new value of the slider and trigger the change event. 
                const value = Number(speedSlider.value), step = Number(speedSlider.step);
                speedSlider.value = value - step;
                speedSlider.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't like the control provided by the slider, you can also control the speed directly using the buttons. In this case, the following variant is possible.

```py
@app.post('/accelerate')
def accelrate():
    v = motor.rpm
    try:
        motor.rpm += int(request.get_json(force=True).get('a'))
        v = motor.rpm
    finally:
        return jsonify(**locals())
```

```js
const accelerate = async (value) => {
    const data = await fetch('/accelerate', {
        method: 'post', 
        body: JSON.stringify({ a: value })
    }).then(resp => resp.ok && resp.json());
    if (!data || !data.v) throw new Error('Error adjusting speed.');
    return data.v;
};

const outputValue = document.getElementById('value');
const buttonAcc = document.getElementById('btn-acc');
buttonAcc.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const v = await accelerate(10);
        outputValue.innerText = v;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});

const buttonDec = document.getElementById('btn-dec');
buttonDec.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const v = await accelerate(-10);
        outputValue.innerText = v;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The second example of code is what I used to solve my problem.